# Android APK: Duplicated resources, why?

Tags: java, android, apk, adt, duplicates

I have seen some similar questions about this issue but no one leads to a solution. Resources are duplicated when apk is build, the apk is twice the size it should be. The apk installs and runs fine anyway.

But, what can I do about this? I using the latest ADT (Android Developer Tools). When I open the apk with winrar, I see the following duplicates (also there are duplicates in the root/res folder):

Here some directory contents in the apk:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your apk. It sometimes happens when something gets messed up in eclipse. I am exactly not sure what got up messed in your case. You can do following things to fix it:

1. Copy your res folder somewhere outside your project.
2. Then delete your res folder along with all the files inside it from eclipse.
3. Then recreate res folder in eclipse and add the files from eclipse.

probably it should work.

Comment: Hi tanks for the tip! I have removed the assets folder (instead of res folder) and recreate it but as normal folder and not as path folder. Restart ADT, Remove all files in the bin folder, clean the project and rebuild manually. This seems to do it, size is now only 1,5MB. Thanks!

Comment: Thats great. happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

i have some solutions for you:

1. reintall eclipse.
2. verify your folder under eclipse
3. Copy your res folder somewhere outside your project.

good luck ;)

Comment: Reinstall is NOT needed. See answer below.